# C# Windows Forms DataGrid - Remove Grid Title/Caption (Not DataGridView)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagrid, windows-ce

Hi I have a DataGrid in my C# Windows CE application.

Here is the code which I used to populate the grid.

```
DataTable dtAddedItems = new DataTable();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dtAddedItems);
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            column.AutoIncrement = true;
            column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add(column);
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("IssueNoteLineId");
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("ItemHeadId");
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("ItemName");
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("IssuedQty");
            dtAddedItems.Columns[0].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
            dtAddedItems.Columns[1].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
            dtAddedItems.Columns[2].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;

            dtgItems.DataSource = dv;
```

And it display the grid when I add Items as below

[image]

And the problem is it display a **Blue Line** (Caption/Title) as in the above image above the Grid Header Columns.

How can I remove it. I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: That doesn't look like part of the datagrid, but more of the form. What happen if you add a button or textbox right before the datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Just set it's CaptionVisible property to false.

I noly know how to add DataGrid via coding.

If you can add it via designer,it will be easier.↓

[add DataGrid in design mode and set it's CaptionVisible property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmG9u.png)